# Line chart (Charts) overflowing to other views on bigger screens - IOS Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

This piece of code works well with iPod 7th gen screen size but overflows to other views on bigger screens.
`rbLineChartView` is the superview of the `lineChartView`.
`rbLineChartView` has height constraint 400 and is present inside a `StackView`.
I tried setting the `superview` frame with lineChartView frame but it did not work.

```
   let lineChartView = LineChartView()
           
   lineChartView.delegate = self
   
   lineChartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false
   lineChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
   lineChartView.leftAxis.enabled = false
   lineChartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
   lineChartView.legend.enabled = false
   lineChartView.scaleXEnabled = false
   lineChartView.scaleYEnabled = false
   lineChartView.setViewPortOffsets(left: 15, top: 15, right: 15, bottom: 15)
   
   let xAxis = lineChartView.xAxis
   xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
   xAxis.granularity = 1.0
   xAxis.enabled = true
   xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
   xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
   xAxis.setLabelCount(4, force: true)
   xAxis.labelFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 7)!
   
   lineChartView.animate(yAxisDuration: 0.5)
   
   // rbLineChartView is the superview which is set to height 400 //
   rbLineChartView.addSubview(lineChartView)
   rbLineChartView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   lineChartView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   lineChartView.centerInSuperview()
   lineChartView.width(to: view)
   lineChartView.heightToWidth(of: view)
   var xAxisValues: Array<String> = []
   for key in sortedBaselineMapKeys {
       // Adding just the hour and seconds as xaxis values since seconds is always 00
       let splitValue = key.split(separator: ":")
       xAxisValues.append(splitValue[0] + ":" + splitValue[1])
   }
   lineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = (ChartFormatter(xAxisValues: xAxisValues) as IAxisValueFormatter)
   
   // Real Time Usage
   let realtimeDataSet = LineChartDataSet(entries: realTimeUsageEntries, label: "Real Time Usage")
   
   // Baseline
   let baselineDataSet = LineChartDataSet(entries: baselineEntries, label: "Baseline")
   
   var dataSets: [LineChartDataSet] = [LineChartDataSet]()
   dataSets.append(realtimeDataSet)
   dataSets.append(baselineDataSet)
   
   lineChartView.data = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
   lineChartView.data?.notifyDataChanged()
   lineChartView.notifyDataSetChanged()
   lineChartView.setNeedsDisplay()
   
   let  marker = LineMarkerView(color: UIColor(named: "ToolTipBackground")!, font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 9)!, textColor: UIColor.white, insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 3.0, left: 7.0, bottom: 7.0, right: 7.0), xAxisValues: xAxisValues)
   marker.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 80.0, height :40.0)
   marker.chartView = lineChartView
   lineChartView.marker = marker
```

**Graph overflowing to other views on iPad Pro 9.7 inch**
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cygcf.png]

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by removing:

```
lineChartView.centerInSuperview()
lineChartView.width(to: view)
lineChartView.heightToWidth(of: view)
```

and adding:

```
lineChartView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

just before the line:

```
lineChartView.data?.notifyDataChanged()
```